# Haskell fold function on tree

Tags: haskell

I'm struggling with this example:

> Write a fold function that folds a function over a tree. (Thus, for
>   example, `fold min t` would find the smallest element in tree.)
>
> ```
> fold :: (a -> a -> a) -> Tree -> a
> ```

*That's my script

```
data Tree = Leaf Int
          | Fork Tree Int Tree
     deriving Show


t0 = Leaf 0
t1 = Fork (Fork (Leaf 1) 2 (Leaf 3)) 4 (Fork (Leaf 5) 6 (Leaf 7))
t2 = Fork (Fork (Fork (Leaf 1) 2 (Leaf 3)) 4 (Leaf 5)) 6 (Leaf 7)

fold :: (a -> a -> a) -> Tree -> a
fold f v (Leaf n) = v
fold f v (Fork l n r) = f (Folk l) (fold f v (Fork r))
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: what have you written ? and what errors you got ?

Comment: What does the data type `Tree` look like? It seems clear it should be `Tree a` so that it can store things of any type `a` in the leaves.

Comment: That's what I did

Answer (score 4):

One thing, in the signature of your function `fold`, you're saying that it'll receive 2 arguments, a binary function (could be an operator), a Tree and returns an `a`. Now, in the defintion you have 3 arguments, `f`, some `v` and a constructor of `Tree`.

The solution could be this one:

```
fold :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Tree -> Int
fold f (Leaf n) = n
fold f (Fork l n r) = f n m
    where
        m = f (fold f l) (fold f r)
```

You need to say that you are returning a `Int` because your `Tree` holds `Int`.

**EDIT**

Furthermore, you can redefine your data with a rigid type variable.

```
data Tree a = Leaf a
            | Fork (Tree a) a (Tree a)
     deriving Show


fold :: (a -> a -> a) -> Tree a -> a
fold f (Leaf n) = n
fold f (Fork l n r) = f n m
    where
        m = f (fold f l) (fold f r)
```

I suggest you to read the documentation of [Data.Foldable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.5.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html). They have an example with a `Tree` data type.

Comment: Nice answer. Yet, I consider the last `Data.Foldable` suggestion misleading. The folding of `Data.Foldable` is the one obtained by flattening the data type to a list, and then folding there. It is not the general catamorphism like the above `fold :: (a -> a -> a) -> Tree a -> a`, so it can easily cause confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Folds can be somewhat mechanically derived from any type. Here's `foldMaybe`:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a

foldMaybe :: r -> (a -> r) -> Maybe a -> r
foldMaybe _ k (Just a) = k a
foldMaybe d _ Nothing  = d
```

To "fold" a data type means that we are going to provide a way of combining each of the possible constructors for that type into a final type `r`. Here, `Maybe` has two constructors: one with 0 values, and one with a single value of type `a`. So, to fold it, we need to provide a value for the `Nothing` case, and a function to convert the `Just a` into an `r`.

Let's look at `list`, and see how `foldr` is derived from it.

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)

           [1]   [2    3    4]             [4]
foldList :: r -> (a -> r -> r) -> List a -> r
```

1. This is the value to use when replacing the `Nil` in the list.
2. This is the function to use for combining the `Cons` case. Since `Cons` has an `a` as it's first value, the function must take an `a`.
3. The second value that `Cons` takes is a `(List a)`, so why are we taking an `r`? Well! We're defining a function that can take a `List a` and return an `r`, so we'll process the rest of the list before combining with the current node.
4. The fold function returns `r`.

What does the implementation look like?

```
foldList nil cons list = case list of
    Nil -> nil
    Cons a as -> cons a (foldList nil cons list)
```

So we replace all of the constructors with their "destructor" counterparts, recursing where necessary.

For trees:

```
data Tree = Leaf Int | Fork Tree Int Tree
```

We have two constructors: one takes an `Int`, and the other takes three parameters `Tree`, `Int`, and `Tree`.

Let us write the type signature!

```
treeFold :: LeafCase r -> ForkCase r -> r
```

Ah, but we have to define `LeafCase`:

```
type LeafCase r = Int -> r
```

Since `Leaf` takes a single Int as parameter, that's what the type of this function must be.

```
type ForkCase r = r -> Int -> r -> r
```

Likewise, we replace all the recursive uses of `Tree` in `Fork` with the `r` type parameter. So our full function looks like:

```
foldTree :: (Int -> r) -> (r -> Int -> r -> r) -> Tree -> r
```

The implementation might start like:

```
foldTree leaf fork tree = case tree of
    Leaf i -> error "halp"
    Fork l i r -> error "complete me?"
```

and I feel confident that you can fill in those holes :)